# How to check a value exists in an integer array - SQL case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a solution to check the existence of a value in an array, so that I need to toggle a column based on that values.

Here is the table structure

```
ID    Name
-------------------
1     Alex
2     John
3     Joel
4     Philip
5     Susan
6     Tim
7     Jerry
-------------------------
```

So the condition is I need all rows but there will be third column which will be based on an existence logic. That is the third column is T if the ID exists in (1,5,7) otherwise the column will be W. So the result will be something like this

```
ID    Name      status
-------------------
1     Alex      T
2     John      W
3     Joel      W
4     Philip    W
5     Susan     T
6     Tim       W
7     Jerry     T
-------------------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, case when id in (1,5,7) 
               then 'T'
               else 'W'
          end as status
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will be helpful.

```
 DECLARE @Test Table
(
    Id Integer,
    Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Test 

SELECT 1,   'AAA'    UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'BBB'   UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  'CCC'    UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  'DDD'    UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  'EEEE'    UNION ALL
SELECT 6,   'FFFF'    UNION ALL
SELECT 7,  'RRRR' 

select *, CASE WHEN Id iN (1,5,7) 
            THEN 'T' 
            ELSE 'D' 
          END AS STATUS 
FROM @Test
```